# Object starts moving and stops moving?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

An object starts moving at point $a$ at $t_a$, and stops at point $b$ at $t_b$ with constant velocity $\vec v$.

Does this sentence mean the objects accelerate tremendously from $0$ at $t_a$ to $\vec v$ at a time very close to $t_a$?

Is the velocity of the object at $t_a$ $0$?

I know if an object with constant speed $s$ travels from $a$ to $b$ in $t$, then the distance travelled is $ts$, by integrating the speed function $s(t)$.

So, if it is ginven that an objects starts moving at $t_a $ and stops at $t_b$ with constant speed $s$, is the distance travelled also $(t_a-t_b)s$ because it is travelling with constant speed from $t=t_a+0.000000001$ and to $t=t_b-0.000000001$?

I have been asked to solve a question that, a speed boat’s speed is $s$, and the water is stationary. The boat starts at $A$ on shore and travels to $B$ along a strait line. Finds its time taken. I want to know exactly what are the assumptions and approximations. The boats start at $A$ and ends at $B$, so its speed at the two places is zero or what?

Answer (score 0):

1> Is the velocity of the object at $t_a= 0 $ ?

Ans: Since it is specifies that from $t_a $to $t_b$ the object is moving at a constant velocity ,  at $t_a $ , the velocity will "v" only . It just means that initially some force led to a constant velocity of v at $t_a $ .

2> is the distance travelled also $(t_a−t_b)s $because it is travelling with constant speed .

Ans: Yes , absolutely right .

The last statement was a bit unclear to me .

Comment: In the last sentence the OP has considered that it starts from rest at a and goes back to rest at b and hence it needs some non-zero $\Delta t$ to attain that velocity.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this sentence mean the objects accelerate tremendously from 0 at $t_a$ to $\vec v$.  at a time very close to {t_a}?

Yes

> Is the velocity of the object at $t_a$ 0?

No. The velocity at $t_a$ is initially undefined. The velocity is 0 before $t_a$ and it's $\vec v$ after $t_a$ so there is discontinuity at $t_a$ (and $t_b$ as well). Determining the value of a function at a discontinuity is complicated and in most cases not needed, so it's best to avoid it in the first place. If you absolutely have to do it, you can make an argument that it's $\vec v /2$ but it's a complicated argument.

> I know if an object with constant speed s travels from a to b in t, then the distance travelled is $t_s$, by integrating the speed function s(t).

Yes.

> So, if it is given that an objects starts moving at $t_a $ and stops at $t_b$ with constant speed $s$, is the distance travelled also $(t_a-t_b)s$

Yes.

The question is somewhat poorly posed since it does require infinite acceleration at $t_a$ and $t_b$ which of course can never happen in the real world. To solve the problem you can safely ignore the detail of what exactly happens at $t_a$ and $t_b$ because the discontinuities are also infinitely short.

Comment: Doses’t the velocity increase to $\vec v$ from 0 at $t_a$ continuously? Why is it undefined at $t_a$? How can it be 0 at one point and discontinue to $\vec v$ for $t$ after $t_a$? I thought all acceleration, velocity, and displacement of any object is continuous. Is it not?